# ActionListener receives no actionperformed event when I push the Select or arrow buttons

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit

I can't figure out why it isn't receiving the action event. I push the arrows and select button and still nothing gets output to the console.

```
import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;
public class LWUITAPP extends javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet implements ActionListener, CommandListener {

        Form form = new Form();
        form.show();
        form.addComponent(list);

        list.setModel(model);
}



public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println ("hii!");
    System.out.println(evt.getKeyEvent());
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {

}
}
```

Comment: I think you've got something missing immediately after the 'public class' line; either that or you've got an extraneous '}' at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put the `keyListener` to the `Form`. You must put this  addKeyListener/addGameKeyListener attached to the `Form`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

All right: I will try to keep it SSCCE.

In order to have events registered, you must add the line...

```
Form form = new Form();
> form.addCommandListener(this)
form.show()
```

...in order to listen to events through your actionPerformed method.

As my proof, take a look at this page on the LWUIT API. 
[https://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Form.html#addCommandListener(com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener)](https://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Form.html#addCommandListener%28com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener%29)

Interestingly, the addCommandListener() method is implemented in place of where addActionListener() would normally be used in the case of Swing applications.